# How to adjust the ratio of my x axis in my line graph in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I am creating a line graph in R using ggplot2. So far the graph is looking fine (I am relatively new to all this), but I have run into an issue trying to adjust my x axis to define the trend a bit better - scale the ratio down slightly. Whenever I use coord_fixed - messing about with it - the scale messes up for the whole graph. What is your advice on using coord_fixed in this situation?

[image: the graph currently]

this is the code

```
ggplot(Met_IOPC, aes(x= Year, y= Total, group = 1))+
  geom_line(color="darkblue")+
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0,1200))+
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `+ theme(aspect.ratio = ...)`?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What is wrong with your current graph?  It looks reasonable to me.  Saying "the scale messes up" isn't very precise.  Also, I would recommend using `coord_cartesian` rather than `scale_<x/y>_zzzz` to set axis limits.  `coord_cartesian` uses all the data to construct the plot and then zooms to the requested area.  Seting `limits` first filters the data and then constructs the plot, which can have unexpected consequences.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to adjust your plot so that the trend line appears steeper.

I think that, due to the difference in range of the x and y axis, you are struggling to find the correct ratio in `coord_fixed`. However, this is only one method to achieve your aim.

If we reproduce your plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

Met_IOPC <- data.frame(Total = c(740, 840, 890, 940, 1040),
                       Year = as.character(2018:2022))

p <- ggplot(Met_IOPC, aes(x= Year, y= Total, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(color="darkblue") +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0, 1200))

p
```

[image]

The simplest way to change the steepness of the line is to drag the plotting window to make it narrower:

[image]

If you wish the plot to retain the same image dimensions, we can either set a very small ratio in `coord_fixed`

```r
p + coord_fixed(ratio = 0.008)
```

[image]

Or adjust the aspect ratio:

```r
p + theme(aspect.ratio = 2)
```

[image]

Or adjust the y axis scale:

```
p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(700, 1100))
```

[image]